# Consecutive animations

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I'm new to Core Animations, I want to fade out two different layers one after another.I write them in a CATransaction block. I wonder if there is better approach to make such animations.

```
[CATransaction begin];

    CABasicAnimation *fadeOutLoadingBar = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeOutLoadingBar.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3];
    fadeOutLoadingBar.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.];
    fadeOutLoadingBar.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeOutLoadingBar.beginTime = [_loadingLayer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    fadeOutLoadingBar.duration = .8;
    fadeOutLoadingBar.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [_loadingLayer addAnimation:fadeOutLoadingBar forKey:nil];

    [self setupCheckMarkLayer]; //initialize _checkMarkLayer 
    CABasicAnimation *fadeOutCheckMark = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeOutCheckMark.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3];
    fadeOutCheckMark.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.];
    fadeOutCheckMark.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeOutCheckMark.beginTime = [_checkMarkLayer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] + 0.5;
    fadeOutCheckMark.duration = 1.0;
    fadeOutCheckMark.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    _checkMarkLayer.opacity = 0.;
    [_checkMarkLayer addAnimation:fadeOutCheckMark forKey:nil];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.delegate finishedLoading];
        [self setupLoadingLayer];
    }];

    [CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Does `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.]` actually work?

Comment: yes,it works :) try it

Answer (score 3):

We have some magic numbers.  Also, why don't we use modern syntax for our `NSNumber` objects?

```
NSNumber *opacityFromValue = @0.3f;
NSNumber *opacityToValue = @0.0f;

CGFloat fadeLoadBarDuration = 0.8;
CGFloat fadeCheckmarkDuration = 1.0;

CGFloat timeCheckmarkOffset = 0.5;
```

And now use these variables in place of the magic numbers.

As an added bonus, we'll get slightly better performance by not having to instantiate the opacity values twice each.  `NSNumber` is an immutable object, so it doesn't matter that we pass the same one both times.

Comment: okay I changed those values thank you, do you also have a suggestion for animation block?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with CoreAnimation.  I'll only comment on what I actually know.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, I do want to comment on this line:

```
[self.delegate finishedLoading];
```

Consider this, there's nothing that prevents your delegate from delegating multiple objects.  Moreover, `finishedLoading` might be a fairly common method name multiple protocols might like to define.

So, let's presume our class that has this delegate is called `MyAnimatingImage`, and the protocol is called `MyAnimatingImageDelegate`.  Rather than looking like this:

```
@protocol MyAnimatingImageDelegate

@required - (void)finishedLoading;

@end
```

We will be better off with a protocol that looks like this:

```
@protocol MyAnimatingImageDelegate

@required - (void)animatingImageDidFinishLoading:(MyAnimatingImage *)animatingImage;

@end
```

And when we call the method, we do so as such:

```
[self.delegate animatingImageDidFinishLoading:self];
```

We pass the delegate a reference to `self`.  Yes, in most cases the delegate will already have a reference to us.  And in a lot of cases, the delegate may not be using multiple objects of this type, so it'll always know what `finishedLoading` is talking about... but consider this case:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.object1 = [MyAnimatingImage animatingImage];
    self.object2 = [MyAnimatingImage animatingImage];

    [object1 beginLoading];
    [object2 beginLoading];
}
```

Now, when `object1` finishes loading and calls `finishedLoading` without passing a reference to itself, how does our delegate know whether `object1` or `object2` is finished loading?  It can't.  It might assume that `object1` is always finished loading first, but that's not always going to be the case, particularly if there's anything asynchronous about the loading.

Comment: you are right. I'm going to change it. thank you for your help.

Comment: I also created a __block variable for self. `__block id< MyAnimatingImage > delegate= self.delegate;`